# How to Configure PHP executable in Visual Studio Code where my setup is Vagrant Ubuntu 16.06 in Windows 10 Host machine

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, vagrant

I have vagrant setup in my machine and I am using Homestead 7 Laravel Box for PHP development. My Host computer is running Windows 10.

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.15.1.

My PHP executable is not set in Visual Studio setting. How can I configure PHP executable in my current development environment?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to install PHP on your windows host

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks, So I have to install Apache and PHP for windows in my windows host and use them in my vs code setting. Then I will have two instances of apache running. Will there be any conflict? I am a bit confused.

Comment: No need to install Apache.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score -2):

To set it in Visual Studio Code, do the following

- Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings.
- Look for the the setting `php.validate.executablePath = null,`.
- Point it to the location of the `php.exe`. (e.g. C:\php\php.exe).
- Finally, copy it onto the `User Settings` pane on the right side then save.
- Output should look like this: `php.validate.executablePath = "C:\php\php.exe",`

Comment: You missed the first step: "Install PHP in Windows".

Answer (score -2):

I managed to fix this by using 2 slashes between each directory, as below...

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.1.9\\php.exe"
```